# The use of Forall in Haskell

Tags: haskell

`Data.Constraint.Forall` provides some quantification over constraints, however I fail to see how it can be used. Consider the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

module Forall where

import Prelude
import Data.Constraint.Forall

class Monoid (f a) => MonoidalFunctor f a

testfun :: Forall (MonoidalFunctor f) => (a -> f a) -> [a] -> f a
testfun = foldMap

testfun' :: Monoid (f a) => (a -> f a) -> [a] -> f a
testfun' = foldMap
```

I thought `testfun` would typecheck because `Forall (MetaMonoid f)` would work like `forall a. Metamonoid f a`, implying `forall a. Monoid (f a)` because of superclass constraint, but it doesn't.

Why does it not work and is there any workaround? I want to avoid having to write a lot of constraints like `MyClass (f MyData)` for different `MyData` types in my function where I know that any useful `f` will have instances for any `f MyData` anyway.

Comment: You have to explicitly bring the instance into scope with e.g. `inst`

Comment: @user2407038 Can you link something were I can read more about this? I can't seem to google what you mean.

Comment: I got it to typecheck with `testfun = foldMap \\ (inst :: Forall (MonoidalFunctor f) :- MonoidalFunctor f a)` which is cool, still would be interested to learn more about that area in Haskell, do I miss something or is there just not a whole lot of documentation on that?

Comment: I think the `constraints` package is very well documented, although it is full of category theory jargon so you may not find that to be the case. But there are plenty of tutorials/blog posts about the subject ("constraint kinds")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `inst`

```
inst :: forall p a. Forall p a :- p a
```

`inst` witness that, if you have `forall a. p a`, then you can set `a` to whatever you please and get `p a` out.

An entailment (`:-`) is

```
newtype a :- b = Sub (a => Dict b)
data Dict a = a => Dict
```

so, by pattern-matching on it, you can reveal the instance within it:

```
testfun :: forall f a. Forall (MonoidalFunctor f) => (a -> f a) -> [a] -> f a
testfun = case inst @(MonoidalFunctor f) @a of Sub Dict -> foldMap
```

(type applications/signatures necessary) or you can use `(\\)`:

```
(\\) :: a => (b => r) -> a :- b -> r
testfun = foldMap \\ inst @(MonoidalFunctor f) @a
```

which reads "given that `a` is true and a value of `r` that also needs `b` to be true, followed by a value that can prove that `b` is true given `a`, make an `r`. If you rearrange a bit

```
(\\) :: (b => c) -> (a :- b) -> (a => c)
```

it looks quite a bit like function composition.

The reason for this dance is simply because it's beyond the reach of GHC to infer that `Forall c` means it can derive `c a` for any `a`; after all, that's why `constraints` exists. So, you have to be a bit more explicit about it.

Comment: hmm... that's interesting. in fact, in intuitionistic logic, entailment and implication are interchangeable. so that indeed is function composition.